# How to make the text being shown on a button fill it horizontally?

Tags: android

[image of current button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Dls.png)

Hi, so i have a problem with a button i am working with...i attached an image for a more specified description...
I would like for the text to be shown horizontally...there is a lot of unused space in the button...and i can't figure out how to do that..

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:paddingLeft="130dip"
        android:paddingRight="130dip"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Thequestion"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        />
```

Comment: add full linearlayout.

Answer (score 1):

you need to reduce paddingLeft and paddingRight. if you want a distance from left and right you should use margin instead of padding.

Edit: you can use theese instead of paddings.

```
android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
android:layout_marginRight="130dp"
```

Comment: would you mind showing me how exactly?
i would realy appreciate it!

Comment: I edited the answer. the 130dp values may not be right you might need to adjust it. you already used         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" you might not need them either.

Answer (score 0):

Please add:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

to your Button

EDIT:

Change

```
android:paddingLeft="130dip"
android:paddingRight="130dip"
```

to

```
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
```

Comment: o.k i did that...but now it only shows a part of the text followed by "..."

Comment: the padding is a lot. Please reduce from 130dip to about 10dip

Comment: yes ok i get that...but this would make my button lose its size...and i would like to be about thos measurmantes the padding gives it...so how to compensate?